Using internal or external ids when storing external data
When storing external data, I usually have two ids. One is external and one is internal. I inevitably need to keep indexes on both ids for lookups. Examples:

Storing stripe customers, products, ids
Storing shopify products, images, variants, etc.
Any external data really

QUESTIONS:

Is this just a necessary part of storing external data or can I be using the external ids only?

Which ids should I use as relational keys between my tables internally?

External ids
Internal ids
Both internal and external ids


In terms of column naming, is it common to have:

id and external_id
internal_id and external_id; or
id and shopify_product_id




This question is similar to: Surrogate key vs Natural key. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

This calls for opinions, but my opinion is that you need no extra artificial "internal" key as long as you always have a unique, immutable "external" key.

Having written many applications with such databases, I would always use your internal id within the database.  There are several reasons (not all will apply to you)

The internal id is smaller and usually numeric, whereas you need to store the external id as a string.
The external id can change, when the store decides on a different supplier. The internal id needs to remain the same.
Some stores deal with multiple suppliers, each having their own external ids.

For naming, call them whatever feels natural to you.
